# Let $f$ be a non-negative continuous function on the real numbers with $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f \mathrm{d}x < \infty$. Is it true that $f$ is bounded?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be a non-negative continuous function on the real numbers with$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f \mathrm{d}x < \infty.$$ Is it true that $f$ is bounded? I was thinking that the Dirac delta function could work since it has measure $0$.

Also I was thinking about the function $(x-r_n)^{-1/2}$ where $r_n$ is an enumeration of the rationals. This is unbounded everywhere and nonnegative.

Comment: No. The graph could consist of flat "zero segments" and  a bunch of very tall, very skinny triangles (with areas such that their sum is finite).

Answer (score 1):

There is a classical counterexample to this: consider the following linear combination of indicator functions $\bar f(x)= \sum\limits_{i=2}^\infty i\mathbf{1}_{ \left[i-\frac{1}{2i^3},i+\frac{1}{2i^3}\right] }(x)$. They all have disjoint support and each of them  has mass $1/i^2$ and so $\bar f$ clearly has finite mass. To make it continuous (or even smooth) just mollify $\bar f$ by some nice bump function $\varphi^\varepsilon$, i.e. define $f= \varphi^\varepsilon* \bar f$ for some $\varepsilon>0$ sufficiently small.

This example is similar in spirit to @DavidMitra's. You could replace the indicator functions by triangles of height $i$ and base $1/i^3$ and you would have the same result but without the need to mollify.